# Confirm that this language is context free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

$$\{a^i b^j c^k \mid i\ne j\text{ or }j\ne k\}$$

Is this language context free? I believe it is based on the following CFG but I would like some confirmation that I'm right.

$$\begin{align*}
&S\to aSbA \mid BbSc \mid\epsilon\\
&A\to cA \mid\epsilon\\
&B\to aB \mid\epsilon
\end{align*}$$

Comment: That grammar obviously generates $\epsilon$, which is not in the language, and it generates $S\to aSbA\to abA\to abcA\to abc$, which is not in the language.  I haven't thought about it carefully, but I think you are barking up the wrong tree, and the language is not context-free.

Comment: My reason for thinking that the language is not context-free is this: To test $i\ne j$, it has to count the `a`s, which it can do on the stack, and then count backwards again as it sees the `b`s, which destroys the count that was on the stack.  Then by the time it gets to the `c`s it has forgotten how many `b`s there were, so it can't test $j\ne k$. This is of course not a proof, since there might be some other strategy for recognizing the language that *does* work, but I think it does suggest what approach to take: try the pumping lemma, as you would for $\{a^ib^ic^i\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grammar doesn’t generate the language. First, $\epsilon=a^0b^0c^0$, so $\epsilon$ is not in the language. It also generates an unwanted $abc$ via $S\Rightarrow aSbA\Rightarrow abA\Rightarrow abcA\Rightarrow abc$. In fact, your grammar generates words of the form $a^ib^jc^k$ such that $i=j$ or $j=k$.

The language is the union of $L_1=\{a^ib^jc^k:i\ne j\}$ and $L_2=\{a^ib^jc^k:j\ne k\}$, and context-free languages are closed under union, so it suffices to show that $L_1$ and $L_2$ are context-free. It’s not hard to design context-free grammars for $L_1$ and $L_2$. For $L_1$, for instance, start by designing a context-free grammar for $\{a^ib^jc^k:i<j\}$; that’s pretty easy, and you can clearly do the same for $\{a^ib^jc^k:i>j\}$. Then just ‘paste’ them together properly to get a context-free grammar for $L_1$, and continue with $L_2$.

Comment: Nice job, Brian, +1.

Comment: So would something like `S->Sc|aSb|Sb|b` satisfy the i<j?

Comment: @Takkun: You don’t want that: $S\Rightarrow aSb\Rightarrow aScb\Rightarrow abcb$. Don’t try to do everything at once. First generate $a^nb^n$, then generate at least one $b$, then generate an arbitrary number of $c$’s.

Comment: `S->Sc|A, A->aAb|B, B->bB|b`?

Comment: @Takkun: Yes, that should work.